# How to add iOS icon for standalone watchOS app

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I have created a standalone Apple Watch app and already added an app icon. However, it doesn't show up on the Apple Watch App on iOS. There are some articles describing how to add an icon by using a "WatchKit Settings Bundle": https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_Preferences_with_the_WatchKit_Settings_Bundle

However, the example project contains an iOS target. How would that work for a standalone watchOS app?

Comment: Have you added the 29x29 2x & 3x "Companion settings icon" in your watch app assets catalog? https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/visual/app-icon/

Comment: Yes. I created a standalone watchOS project in latest Xcode and populated the predefined `AppIcon` asset.

Comment: Did you install a Testflight build?  From memory Xcode builds don't show in the watch app on the phone.

Comment: Haha, no. That is an interesting hint! I can't verify right now. Will you post this as an answer? I'll accept it as soon as I have double checked.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone facing this problem in 2023 (Xcode 15)

Here's what you can do:

1. Add the AppIcon to the Watch target (as you normally would, in the Assets.xcassets file next to the AccentColor)
2. **In the inspector**, select the **AppIcon** and in the **Attributes Inspector** change the iOS option from **None** to **Single Size** (or All Sizes if you want to customize it further)

> On the AppIcon change the iOS option from **None** to **Single Size**